# inequality of sums

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I think about the following inequality:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \right)
$$

Is the inequality true for all $a_i$ and $b_i$, or just correct with $a_i>0$ and $b_i>0$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Is there anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: search in  google by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. It will help you

Answer (score 3):

This inequality is false if you allow one $a_{i}$ or $b_{i}$ to be non positive. For example, take $n=2$ and : $a_{1} = 1$, $a_{2} = 2$, $b_{1} = -1$ and $b_{2} = 0$. Then : $\sum_{i} a_{i}b_{i} =  -1 $ and $\big( \sum_{i} a_{i} \big) \big( \sum_{i} b_{i} \big) = -3$. Hence, you get : $-1 \leq -3$.

However, the inequality holds if all $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are non-negative. You can prove it by induction. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ and $(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n+1},b_{1},\ldots,b_{n+1})$ be non-negative real numbers. Assume that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}b_{i} \leq \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \big) \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \big)$. Then :

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{i}b_{i} & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}b_{i} + a_{n+1}b_{n+1} \\
 & \leq & \color{blue}{\big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \big) \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \big)} + \color{blue}{a_{n+1}b_{n+1}} \\
 & \leq & \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{i} \big) \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} b_{i} \big) 
\end{eqnarray*}

because :

$$ \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{i} \big) \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} b_{i} \big) = \color{blue}{\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \big) \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \big)} + \underbrace{a_{n+1} \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \big) + b_{n+1} \big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \big)}_{\geq 0} + \color{blue}{a_{n+1}b_{n+1}} $$